# Cakephp password field already filled but with hashed password

Tags: cakephp, passwords

In my cakephp app, once a user is added, i try to login, when firefox automaticaly fills the password field but with the hashed password.

Does it come from my browser, or my code ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am confused. Do you mean the '*' if so that is because your type='password' if you mean the b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5 in the database that is from the php encryption. Anything else and I am lost.

Comment: The password field is filled with ********************.

Comment: that is because of the type='password' on your input field on the login form.

Comment: Ok, then what should I do with that field ?

Comment: <input type='text' name='password' /> or whatever the name of the input field is

Comment: When you say "automatically fills the password field", do you mean when you type in your username, the password field is filled?  If so, that is something your browser is doing.  Also the asterisk instead of normal text is not hashed.  Password inputs display all characters as asterisk for security reasons -- people could read your password as you type otherwise.  The actual data that is sent by a password field will be unchanged, however.

Comment: Yes I mean that when I type a username, the password field fills by itself. But it fills it with the hashed password.

For exemple, my password is "password", once hashed it becomes "1zc51qsd6c519s8d1s6c1r". When my password field is automaticaly filled, it will show "********************".

Comment: I believe the original poster is saying that the password field is autopopulated but with the incorrect value. The value it is populating (hidden by the ***)  is that of the unhashed password which would be "1zc51qsd6c519s8d1s6c1r". It should be autopopulated with "password" hidden by "********"...that is if you want it to autopopulate in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes, the number of asterisks is not equal to the length of the actual password when a browser fills up a web form. Are you able to login successfully? If yes, then your normal password is being auto-populated with an unequal number of asterisks. Check the length of your hashed password in the database and count the number of asterisks in the auto-populated password. Hopefully, they aren't equal.